# Unity: Mlagents-learn issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, ml-agent

I'm kinda new to Unity so I may have done something wrong. But I did follow the installation guide from start to finish that can be found on the mlagents GitHub installation guide. My guess is I did something wrong in the part python package install, although I did follow that as well.
However when I try to run the mlagents-learn command `mlagents-learn config/ppo/3DBall.yaml --run-id=first3DBallRun` in cmd I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Cannot find the assigned module.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\EmilN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\mlagents-learn-script.py", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('mlagents', 'console_scripts', 'mlagents-learn')()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
return self.resolve()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
File "d:\unity stuff\ml-agents-master\ml-agents-master\ml-agents\mlagents\trainers\learn.py", line 13, in <module>
from mlagents import tf_utils
File "d:\unity stuff\ml-agents-master\ml-agents-master\ml-agents\mlagents\tf_utils\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from mlagents.tf_utils.tf import tf as tf # noqa
File "d:\unity stuff\ml-agents-master\ml-agents-master\ml-agents\mlagents\tf_utils\tf.py", line 3, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf # noqa I201
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
from tensorflow_core import *
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
module = self._load()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "c:\users\emiln\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Cannot find the assigned module.
```

Given the error messages, I am assuming the issue is with Python. Quick notes as well, I'm not in a virtual environment, not sure if this matters. I just wanted to do some simple tests for a thesis project. Also is there a way to pull graphs out from the training session?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have all dependencies installed? Installing `mlagents` with anaconda (or another virtual environment) and check if you get the same error is something that I would try.

I learnt the basics for Unity ML-agents by the Unity Hummingbird tutorial by Immersive Limit, https://learn.unity.com/course/ml-agents-hummingbirds, in which he also explains the installation options in a nice way. I could really recommend that course.

In the same course, they go through how you can visualize your training with Tensorboard. Or read about it in [the docs](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Using-Tensorboard.md).